# Short story about wives fattening husbands up for competition

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in an anthology in my middle school library in the late 80's so it was probably from the 70's. It was about wives fattening their husbands, with their consent, for a competition. The husband had been a sports player, possibly football, that still tried to stay in shape despite his wife fattening him up. He was actually able to walk up the stairs whereas all the others had to be lifted to the scale with a crane. In the end he won and as per the rules:

> The winner got to choose how he was cooked and fed to the losers. He chose being served raw.

Does anyone know this story?

Comment: What is the question? :)  (the story sounds interesting!)

Comment: The husbands consent to being slaughtered if they win?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Gladys's Gregory" by John Anthony West](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74542).

> A woman named Gladys is depressed because her husband Gregory couldn't be worse: He's kind, considerate, faithful, energetic, handsome, intelligent and in perfect shape, the asshole. Too bad he can't be a fat slob like any other husband, so Gladys starts doing her best to fatten him up. Why?

Also, from a TV Tropes entry mentioning it:

> John Anthony West's short story "Gladys's Gregory" involves a society of sorts in which women encourage their husbands to put on huge amounts of weight, then slaughter and eat the fattest guy (prepared according to his last wishes) after an annual weigh-in. And then Gregory squicks everyone by asking to be served raw.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I actually have this is a disintegrating paperback called "Twenty Years of the Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction." The title of the story is "Gladys's Gregory" and the writer is John Anthony West.